# WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted firing multiple times?

Tags: c#

So right now, on a button press, I have this:

```
 wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
 wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;

 Thread nT = new Thread(() => wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=" + movID + "&plot=full&r=json")));
 nT.Start();
```

With wc being a webclient. Under wc_DownloadStringCompleted I have this:

```
 Dictionary<String, String> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(e.Result);
 Movies.Add(CREATE_MOVIE(values));
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
 {
     this.Text = "Add Multiple Movies";
 }));
```

However, when the webclient has finished downloading the string it will run the amount of times that there is a index of Movies. So for instance, the first time the webclient runs it will return 1 movie and then the next time the webclient runs it will return 2 movies for a total of 3 movies when there should only be two. Here is an example:

After running the webclient twice with different urls it returns:

> - The Principle
> - Interstellar
> - Interstellar

And three different urls:

> - The Principle
> - Interstellar
> - Interstellar
> - Star Wars: Episode VII
> - Star Wars: Episode VII
> - Star Wars: Episode VII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you initiate a download, you subscribe your `...Completed` and `...ProgressChanged` handlers to the same object again. This adds a new instance of the subscription to each event with each download. And so when the events are raised, each subscription is invoked, resulting in the multiple invocations of your handlers (the same thing is happening for the `...Completed` event, but likely the way you are handling the event prevents the multiple-invocation issue from being immediately noticeable).

Change the anonymous method in your `...Completed` handler to something like this:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
{
    this.Text = "Add Multiple Movies";
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
}));
```